My Canvas is not working with form Element
This is my code
<?php
$pair = "BTCUSDT";
$frame = 1;
$candle = 30;
if(isset($_POST['pair'])){

 $pair = $_POST['pair'];
 $frame = $_POST['frame'];
 $candle = $_POST['candle'];

}
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php echo $pair; ?> Live Chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> Say some title

<canvas id="btcusdt-chart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
    
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('btcusdt-chart').getContext('2d');
        var chart = null;

        // Function to fetch BTC/USDT data from PHP
        function fetchData() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'fetch_data.php?pair=<?php echo $pair; ?>&frame=<?php echo $frame; ?>&candle=<?php echo $candle; ?>',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    updateChart(data);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            });
        }

        // Function to update the chart with new data
        function updateChart(data) {
            if (chart) {
                // Update existing chart
                chart.data.labels = data.timestamps;
                chart.data.datasets[0].data = data.btcusdt_values;
                chart.update();
            } else {
                // Create new chart
                chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: data.timestamps,
                        datasets: [{
                            label: '<?php echo $pair; ?>',
                            data: data.btcusdt_values,
                            borderColor: 'blue',
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            fill: false
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        responsive: true,
                        maintainAspectRatio: false,
                        scales: {
                            xAxes: [{
                                type: 'time',
                                time: {
                                    unit: 'minute'
                                }
                            }],
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: false
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        // Update chart every 10 seconds
        setInterval(fetchData, 10000);

        // Initial fetch
        fetchData();
    </script>

</body>
</html>

It is not working because canvas is stressing vertically.  If I remove

Say some title


it works fine. Why and how to solve it?

Your question is unclear. You mention a form element in the title of your question, but it's not present in your code. Did you forget to add it? How are you posting pair, frame and candle? Also - "canvas is stressing vertically" - what does that mean, exactly? Can you please post a sample JSON of what you're getting from your fetchData() function?
